# Can't find the template - Django

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-templates

In my Django project I have two *apps*, called `data_app` and `user_app`. The `data_app` works perfectly, but `user_app` not.

When I write in my browser `http://127.0.0.1:8000/login/` appears the following error,

> django.template.exceptions.TemplateDoesNotExist: /login.html

Probably I'm forgetting something, but I don't know what. Then, I show the different parts and my structure,

**views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render

# Create your views here.
from django.shortcuts import redirect
from django.contrib.auth.models import User, auth
from django.contrib import messages

def login(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        username = request.POST['uname']
        password = request.POST['pass']
        user = auth.authenticate(username=username, password=password)

        if user is not None:
            auth.login(request,user)
            return redirect('/data_app/data-bbdd/')
        else:
            return redirect('login')

    else:
        print('Hello2')
        return render(request, '/login.html')

def logout(request):
    auth.logout(request)
    return redirect('login')
```

**urls.py (user_app)**

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path

from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('login/', views.login, name='login'),
    path('logout/', views.logout, name='logout')
]
```

**urls.py ("general" app)**

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, re_path, include

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    re_path('', include('applications.data_app.urls')),
    re_path('', include('applications.user_app.urls'))
]
```

**Estructure**

[image]

I suppose I'm forgetting some path, but I can't see were.

**Note** The `print('Hello2')` from `views.py` is working, the the problem is in `return render(request, '/login.html')`.

Thank you very much!

Comment: can you show your TEMPLATES array in settings.py

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`return render(request, '/login.html')` replace it to `return render(request, 'user_app/login.html')`

Answer (score 2):

As shyotov already answered the mistake is in `render(request, '/login.html')`, because your template is located under `user_app` folder.

When building your Django app, you should try to keep your templates separated.

You should bundle your data_app templates inside your data_app. Inside the following folder: `applications/data_app/templates/data_app/data.html`

For your user_app it would be the following:
`applications/user_app/templates/user_app/login.html`

To make this work you need to update your settings.py: (see https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/templates/)

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [
            os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates'),
        ],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
        },
    },
]
```

Nonetheless, within your `views.py` you would still have to call: `render(request, 'user_app/login.html')`, but you could keep your templates close to where they belong to.

You should use `applications/templates` for common shared templates. Usually there would be a `base.html` inside this folder, where other templates can extend from.